# Differentiability of a Metric Tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

As an introduction to Metric Tensors, I read the conditions to be met for a metric includes it being *differentiability class* $C^2$ i.e. all second-order partial derivatives of $g_{ij}$ exists and are continuous.

But the metrics I have encountered in books are euclidean, cylindrical or polar and others which doesn't seem to hold this property. I am definitely going wrong with this?

for euclidean coordinates    $g_{ij} = diag(1,1,1) $ and $∂g_{ij} = 0 $ which leaves no room second.

Comment: Constant functions are still differentiable.

Comment: *which leaves no room for second* why do you think this?

Comment: You have a point for polar and cylindrical coordinates: They only provide a good metric tensor on a subset of the space (remember that a chart of a manifold does not have to cover the entire manifold, this is not even possible for manifolds that are not homeomorphic to the Euclidean space).

Comment: @KyleKanos by the _existing_ differential I understood that it would be a non-zero. should it not?

Comment: @SebastianRiese I imagine by being a subset you meant that some elements may vanish for the second derivative but other may remain... non-zero?

Comment: @syed the derivative is indeed zero. And the derivative of a constant, even zero, is still zero.

Comment: I don't talk about vanishing, if the deriative vanishes it still exists, I talk about non-definedness.